# Linking a script to glew and GLFW c++

Tags: c++, opengl, netbeans, glfw, glew

I been following a tutorial to create a simple program which displays a window with an unshaded triangle drawn in it. To do this I am using the glew library and the GLFW library however after adding in the following code:

```
do{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (VOID*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
} while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == false);
```

I got this error (full message not shown):

```
undefined reference to `glDrawArrays'
```

I think this could be because of a problem with how my project is linked however other functions from glew are being called without errors which is what confuses me. I'm using NetBeans for my IDE and MinGW64 as my compiler on a 64 bit windows 10 installation. The project includes the following places:

```
../../../../../Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/include/GLFW
../../../../../Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/include
../../../../../Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/include/GL
```

And the library files I use are located at these locations:

```
../../../../../Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/glew32.dll
../../../../../Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/lib/glfw3.dll
```

Comment: glDrawArrays is an opengl function, its not part of glew/glfw. Most likely you forgot to link with opengl itself (opengl32.lib on windows)

Comment: This corrected the error, thank you Borgleader